# Displaying a particulat value from MYSQL database with react native

Tags: mysql, react-native

how to retrieve a particular row from MySQL database and to use them in react native?

Comment: do you have any backend which connects with database or you are directly trying to access from react-native?

Comment: I am using php as my backend

Comment: so , just make a rest api in backend and call it in react-native app so that it can get the value from database via php

Comment: [{"id":"1","cus_name":"k","cmpny_name":"k","gst_no":"k","mob_no":"k","user_id":"k","password":"k"}]

Comment: this is my php output. I have encoded it into json but still couldn't retrieve particular data for example id from this array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, suppose you get an array of responses from the api call in backend (i.e php) , like `[{"id":"1","cus_name":"k","cmpny_name":"k","gst_no":"k","mob_no":"k","user_id":"k","password":"k"}]`

So suppose youget response in a variable eg

```
response = [{"id":"1","cus_name":"k","cmpny_name":"k","gst_no":"k","mob_no":"k","user_id":"k","password":"k"}]
```

Now to extract id of first element just do ,

`response[0]['id']` , and this will give out the value 1. coz `id` is 1.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: if I have a state variable userDetails and I set my response JSON to that variable for example this.setState({userDetails:responseJson}). in this case how to access each value in that array ?

Comment: this.state.userDetails[0]['id']

Comment: did it help you?

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Roy, it worked fine